# MVC Jquery post get sent twice

Tags: jquery, post, model-view-controller

This seems like a reccuring problem, but I can't find the right solution for my situation. My code seems pretty simple, yet I cannot find the problem.

Here is the whole code. When I click on the "Commencer" button. A model pop up and if I cancel it, everything is fine. However, if I click on OK, the "ConfirmerFamille" action is posted twice and therefore the action is performed twice, which is not the ideal solution at all.

Here is the whole code for the Razor part.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sélection de la famille d'emplois";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<br /><br />
<div class="form-group ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.Label("Veuillez sélectionner la famille d'emplois qui vous intéresse", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })<br/>
            @Html.DropDownList("IdFamille", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Familles"], "Sélectionner...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn-bootstrap-dialog btn btn-primary" id="btnDebut" >Commencer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <p>Une fois que vous commencez l’évaluation, il est impossible de changer de famille d’emplois.<br /><br />Continuer ?</p>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="confirmOk">Ok</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.btn-bootstrap-dialog').click(function () {

        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#bootstrapDialog').html(data);
            $('#bootstrapDialog').modal('show');
            $('#ModalPopUp').find('#myModalLabel').html($(this).attr("title"));
        });
    });

    $('.btn-primary').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var std = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#myModal1').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        })
        .on('click', '#confirmOk', function (e) {
            $.post('@Url.Action("ConfirmerFamille", "Interet")',
                {
                    IdFamille: $('#IdFamille').val()
                    });

            $('#myModal1 ').modal('hide');
            window.location.reload();

            });
     });
});
```

Comment: You're binding the `on()` to the modal each time the method happens.  So if you click the btn-primary twice, the nested click handler will be executed twice.  This is a prime example of why people say to never bind event handlers in other event handlers.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I just started using JQuery, so I don't really know how else to do it. What would you recommend ?

Comment: Given that your `on()` is in the delegate form, I would say to do that part outside of the click handler.  Leave the modal()` part in there, but move the `on()` outside.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you attach to the "click" event of "#confirmOk"-button everytime you click on "Commencer".

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.btn-primary').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var std = this.id;
  
  //leave the modal part in the click logic
  $('#myModal1').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    });
});

//move this part outside of the click handler, on it's own
//so it only happens once
$('#myModal1').on('click', '#confirmOk', function(e) {
  $.post('@Url.Action("ConfirmerFamille", "Interet")', {
    IdFamille: $('#IdFamille').val()
  });

  $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
  window.location.reload();
});
```